# Cramer-Rao lower bound for the variance of the unbiased estimator of $\tau(\theta)$

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Given the pdf $f(x;\theta)=\frac{1}{\pi[1+(x-\theta)^2]}$ ; $-\inf < x<\inf$, $-\inf < \theta<\inf$

Show that the Cramer-Rao lower bound is 2/n

where n is the sample size.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2158292/cramer-rao-lower-bound-in-cauchy-distribution/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- you have the assumption that the samples are independent.

2- calculate the log likelihood ratio for $n$ samples. All likelihoods are multiplicative due to independence.

3- find the second derivative of the log likelihood function.

4- take the minus expectation w.r.t $X$ of what you've found at 3. And take the -1st power.

See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramér–Rao_bound for more information

Comment: At step (3) i came up with the result $2\times \frac{[(x-\theta)^2-1]}{[1+(x-\theta)^2]^2}$. is this right? i am not understanding how will i get the value 2 taking  the minus expectation w.r.t X of what i've found at 3. And take the -1st power.

Comment: There is a problem at 2. You need to have an expression which has the number of samples. Let $X$ be $X_i$ and multiply $n$ of them. You will have multiplications somewhere in your expression. When you take the logarithm it will become a summation.